# I want to spend more time on splash images

Tags: react-native, webview

**I want to spend more time on splash images
I want to set the time of the splash image
Splash image only appears for 1 second and then white screen. I want the first loading screen to appear only as splash image**
This is my app,js file. Please add the code here

```
    *import React, { useRef, useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
    import { BackHandler, Platform, StyleSheet,ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
    import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";

    export default function App() {
    const webView = useRef();

   const [canGoBack, setCanGoBack] = useState(false);
  const handleBack = useCallback(() => {
    if (canGoBack && webView.current) {
      webView.current.goBack();
      return true;
    }
    return false;`enter code here`
  }, [canGoBack]);

  useEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", handleBack);
    return () => {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", handleBack);
    };
  }, [handleBack]);
const App = () => (
  <View style={[styles.container, styles.horizontal]}>
    <ActivityIndicator />
    <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
    <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="#0000ff" />
    <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#00ff00" />
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  horizontal: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    padding: 10,
  },
});

  const platformStyles = StyleSheet.create({
    webView: Platform.OS === 'ios' 
      ? { marginTop: 30, marginBottom: 40 }
      : { marginTop: 30 }
  });


  return (
    <WebView
      ref={webView}
      source={{ uri: "https://www.talesrunnerbestguild.co.kr/" }}
      style = {platformStyles.webView}
      onLoadProgress={(event) => setCanGoBack(event.nativeEvent.canGoBack)}
    />
  );

}*
```

Comment: For your future posts it's advisable to give the specific part of the code that is not working properly, and more importantly give your version of react native. And also you can tell whether you are using expo or bare react native project because it may imply linking. Ultimately you need to define a setTimeout() function for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this code for you!

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  BackHandler,
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

const DELAY_BEFORE_WEBVIEW = 10; // <--- seconds before webview load

export default function App() {
  // ref
  const webView = useRef();

  // callbacks
  const handleBack = useCallback(() => {
    if (canGoBack && webView.current) {
      webView.current.goBack();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
    `enter code here`;
  }, [canGoBack]);

  // effects
  useEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBack);
    return () => {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBack);
    };
  }, [handleBack]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }, 1000 * DELAY_BEFORE_WEBVIEW);
  }, []);

  // states
  const [canGoBack, setCanGoBack] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <WebView
        ref={webView}
        source={{ uri: 'https://www.talesrunnerbestguild.co.kr/' }}
        style={styles.webView}
        onLoadProgress={(event) => setCanGoBack(event.nativeEvent.canGoBack)}
      />
      {isLoading && <CenterLoader />}
    </View>
  );
}

const CenterLoader = () => (
  <View style={styles.loaderContainer}>
    <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#00ff00" />
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1 },
  loaderContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    position: 'absolute',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor:'white' // <-- comment this to show webview while loading
  },
  webView:
    Platform.OS === 'ios'
      ? { marginTop: 30, marginBottom: 40 }
      : { marginTop: 30 },
});
```

Comment: I want to keep my drawings on the screen, not the white screen The file is in /assets/splash.png/

Comment: Please import the file, and put <Image/> in <CenterLoader /> component.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/image

Comment: <View style={styles.loaderContainer}>
    <Image source={require('/assets/splash.png/')} style={{height:100,width:100}}/></View>

Comment: if you can share your project here, I can help you,
https://snack.expo.dev

make sure to log-in and share a link

Comment: I think you are talking about the splash screen which comes with the OS.

Please check this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-splash-screen

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/@kimjunseok/talesrunner23

Comment: help me I don't know because it's my first time

Comment: I'm not able to understand your problem.
As per the code shared by you, your issue is not in this code.

Comment: The program works, but if you press the Back button once, the app will turn off. I have to press the Back button twice to end the app, and once I press it, I want to go to the whole page @Raj Rohit Yadav

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/backhandler